# Sproutcore version 2.0 creating of models

Tags: sproutcore

how can we write models in sproutcore version2.0,if their are more functionalities to do,for example i have to do multiple selection and filtering lists.

Answer (score 0):

Sproutcore is heavily MVC.  That means the concerns of the Model are separated from the concerns of the views.

Given that, your model objects should only have code around model concerns.  Selection and filtering are different concerns.